# Copy only the files from the intersection of two directories over from directory 1 to directory 2

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, command-line

Suppose I have:

```
dir_1
- file_a
- subdir_0
  - file_b
- file_c
```

```
dir_2
- file_a
- subdir_0
  - file_b
```

I want to copy over every file that exists in both directories to dir_2. In the above example, this would mean `file_a` and `subdir_0/file_b`.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this in bash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using find and a shell loop:

```
find dir_2 -type f -exec sh -c '
for dst; do
  src=dir_1${dst#dir_2}
  if test -f "$src"; then
    echo cp "$src" "$dst"
  fi
done' sh {} +
```

Remove `echo` to actually copy the files.

Answer (score 2):

One `find/while/read` idea:

```
while read -r tgt
do
    src="${tgt//dir_2/dir_1}"
    [[ -f "${src}" ]] && echo cp "${src}" "${tgt}"     # if satisfied with output then remove the 'echo'
done < <(find dir_2 -type f)
```

This generates:

```
cp dir_1/file_a dir_2/file_a
cp dir_1/subdir_0/file_b dir_2/subdir_0/file_b
```